# Can we use water as fuel for nuclear thermal space propulsion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, rocket-science, space-travel

As I know, the working fuel of choice is Hydrogen because of its low molecular mass. When it comes to escape velocity, the estimate vary too much, from $8$km/s to $50$km/s (gas core reactor).

Wouldn't it be better to use water as a fuel since it's so much easier to store?

If we used water as a fuel, what would the escape velocity be (since it's molecular mass is higher than hydrogen)?

Is there a formula? What's the relation between the fuel's molecular mass, temperature and escape velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by *escape velocity* you mean *exhaust velocity*, then the velocity comes from the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). This gives the velocity distribution of the particles in a gas as a function of temperature. For our purposes we can use the most probably speed, i.e. the peak in the distribution, as a rough estimate and this is given by:

$$ V_e = \sqrt{\frac{2kT}{M}} $$

where $T$ is the temperature to which the reactor heats the propellant.

So as you increase the molecular mass of the propellant the exhaust velocity falls as $1/\sqrt{M}$. The problem is that if you carry a mass $m$ of propellant the total possible momentum change is $mV_e$, so for propellant with a greater molecular weight you need to carry a greater mass of the propellant, $m$, but then the extra weight of propellant adds to the weight of your rocket.